# Create text file in folder

Tags: python, file, variables, directory, txt

I'm trying to create a text file that is named using a variable in my program. Only problem is, I can't specify a directory when i'm naming it using a variable. (vac_postcode is the variable i'm using to name the file)

```
centrebypostcode = open(C:\Users\Rich\Desktop\Assignment\Centre\vac_postcode + ".txt"', "a+")
            centrebypostcode.write("\n")
            centrebypostcode.write(vac_center)
            centrebypostcode.close()
```

I'm using "a+" because I need the program to create the text file if it doesn't exist, but if it does, it just appends what I need it to, to the text file. (This is my understanding of the usage of "a+")

`open(r'C:\Users\Rich\Desktop\Assignment\Centre\vac_postcode + ".txt"', "a+" ')` does not work either, unfortunately.

Comment: Try `centrebypostcode = open("C:\Users\Rich\Desktop\Assignment\Centre\" + vac_postcode + ".txt", "a+")`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to keep the variable name *outside* the quoted string, change the line to

```
centrebypostcode = open(r"C:\Users\Rich\Desktop\Assignment\Centre" + "\\" + vac_postcode + ".txt", "a+")
```

**Edited**: the raw string literal cannot have the last backslash, so you need to concatenate that separately.

Comment: As the edit queue is full, I can't edit it. Wouldn't that produce an error? There shouldn't be a `'` after `".txt"`.

Comment: Thanks to you, I was able to get a lot of other things working in my program!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like that quotation is wrong.

try with this

```py
centrebypostcode = open(r"C:\Users\Rich\Desktop\Assignment\Centre\{}.txt".format(vac_postcode), "a+")
```

Answer (score 1):

I just try to be more descriptive

```
filenames = ["my_file1","my_file2"]
for filename in filenames:
    filename = f"C:\Users\Rich\Desktop\Assignment\Centre\vac_postcode\{filename}.txt"
    with open(filename, "a+") as fh:
        fh.write("Hello world")
```